# How to create multi sheet excel in MarkLogic

Tags: excel, xquery, openxml, marklogic, xlsx

I want to create excel file having two sheets in single workbook. When I tried using following code, it creates a workbook which cannot be opened.
However when I create a single sheet it works.
Please find attached code for both cases and let me know what have I missed.

Creating single sheet excel (working).

```
declare namespace ms = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" ;
declare namespace ns2 = "http://www.example.com/";

declare function local:AgentReport() 
{ 
<AgentReport>
    <Report>
        <GroupNumber>1</GroupNumber>
        <Quotes>1</Quotes>
        <Converted>1</Converted>
        <Conv_Rate>1</Conv_Rate>
    </Report>
    <Report>
        <GroupNumber>2</GroupNumber>
        <Quotes>2</Quotes>
        <Converted>2</Converted>
        <Conv_Rate>2</Conv_Rate>
    </Report>
</AgentReport>
};
declare function local:getRows( $x ) as element(ms:row)* 
{ 
    let $first-row :=
            <ms:row> 
            {
            for $i in $x/*/*[1]/child::element()
            return 
            <ms:c t="inlineStr"> <ms:is> <ms:t>{fn:node-name($i)}</ms:t> </ms:is> </ms:c> 
            }
            </ms:row>
    return 
        (
        $first-row,

        for $each in $x//Report
        return
        <ms:row> 
        {
        for $i in $each/*
        return 
        <ms:c t="inlineStr"> <ms:is> <ms:t>{$i/string()}</ms:t> </ms:is> </ms:c> 
        }
        </ms:row>
        )
};

declare function local:generate-simple-xl-ooxml( $content-types as node(), $workbook as node(), $rels as node(), $workbookrels as node(), $sheet1 as node() ) as binary() 
{ 
    let $manifest :=    <parts xmlns="xdmp:zip"> 
                        <part>[Content_Types].xml</part> 
                        <part>workbook.xml</part> 
                        <part>_rels/.rels</part> 
                        <part>_rels/workbook.xml.rels</part> 
                        <part>sheet1.xml</part> 
                        </parts> 
    let $parts := ($content-types, $workbook, $rels, $workbookrels, $sheet1) 
    return xdmp:zip-create($manifest, $parts)
};

let $content-types := <Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> 
                      <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
                      <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/> 
                      <Override PartName="/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/> 
                      <Override PartName="/sheet1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/> 
                      </Types> 

let $workbook :=  <workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"> 
                  <sheets> 
                  <sheet name="Sheet1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1" /> 
                  </sheets> 
                  </workbook> 

let $rels :=  <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"> 
              <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="workbook.xml"/> 
              </Relationships> 

let $workbookrels :=  <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"> 
                      <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="sheet1.xml"/> 
                      </Relationships> 

let $date := xs:string(fn:current-date())

let $day := fn:tokenize($date, "\+")[1]

let $xml := local:AgentReport()

let $page := xdmp:tidy(xdmp:quote($xml), 
                      <options xmlns="xdmp:tidy">
                      <input-xml>true</input-xml>
                      </options>)[2]

let $tables := $page

let $sheet1 :=   <worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"> 
                <sheetData> {local:getRows($tables)} </sheetData> 
                </worksheet> 

let $package := local:generate-simple-xl-ooxml($content-types, $workbook, $rels, $workbookrels, $sheet1) 

let $filename := "ExcelTest.xlsx" 

let $disposition := concat("attachment; filename=""",$filename,"""") 

let $x := xdmp:add-response-header("Content-Disposition", $disposition) 

let $x := xdmp:set-response-content-type("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") 

let $insertReport := xdmp:document-insert(concat("/GroupNumberReport/Group-", $day, ".xlsx"), $package, (), "GroupReport")

let $saveReport := xdmp:save(concat("C:\EriePoc\DataStage-Demo\Report\Group-", $day, ".xlsx"), $package)

return fn:true()
```

Creating two sheets excel (not working i.e creating corrupt excelsheet).

```
declare namespace ms = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" ;
declare namespace ns2 = "http://www.example.com/";

declare function local:AgentReport() 
{ 
<AgentReport>
    <Report>
        <GroupNumber>1</GroupNumber>
        <Quotes>1</Quotes>
        <Converted>1</Converted>
        <Conv_Rate>1</Conv_Rate>
    </Report>
    <Report>
        <GroupNumber>2</GroupNumber>
        <Quotes>2</Quotes>
        <Converted>2</Converted>
        <Conv_Rate>2</Conv_Rate>
    </Report>
</AgentReport>

};

declare function local:getRows( $x ) as element(ms:row)* 
{ 
    let $first-row :=
            <ms:row> 
            {
            for $i in $x/*/*[1]/child::element()
            return 
            <ms:c t="inlineStr"> <ms:is> <ms:t>{fn:node-name($i)}</ms:t> </ms:is> </ms:c> 
            }
            </ms:row>
    return 
        (
        $first-row,

        for $each in $x//Report
        return
        <ms:row> 
        {
        for $i in $each/*
        return 
        <ms:c t="inlineStr"> <ms:is> <ms:t>{$i/string()}</ms:t> </ms:is> </ms:c> 
        }
        </ms:row>
        )
};

declare function local:generate-simple-xl-ooxml( $content-types as node(), $workbook as node(), $rels as node(), $workbookrels as node(), $sheet1 as node(), $sheet2 as node() ) as binary() 
{ 
    let $manifest :=    <parts xmlns="xdmp:zip"> 
                        <part>[Content_Types].xml</part> 
                        <part>workbook.xml</part> 
                        <part>_rels/.rels</part> 
                        <part>_rels/workbook.xml.rels</part> 
                        <part>sheet1.xml</part>
                        <part>sheet2.xml</part>
                        </parts> 
    let $parts := ($content-types, $workbook, $rels, $workbookrels, $sheet1, $sheet2) 
    return xdmp:zip-create($manifest, $parts)
};

let $content-types := <Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> 
                      <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
                      <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/> 
                      <Override PartName="/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/> 
                      <Override PartName="/sheet1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>
                                <Override PartName="/sheet2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/>
                      </Types> 

let $workbook :=  <workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"> 
                  <sheets>  
                  <sheet name="Sheet1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1" />
                          <sheet name="Sheet2" sheetId="2" r:id="rId2" />
                  </sheets> 
                  </workbook> 

let $rels :=  <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"> 
              <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="workbook.xml"/>
                    <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="workbook.xml"/>             
              </Relationships> 

let $workbookrels :=  <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"> 
                      <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="sheet1.xml"/>
                                <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="sheet2.xml"/>                    
                      </Relationships> 

let $date := xs:string(fn:current-date())

let $day := fn:tokenize($date, "\+")[1]

let $xml := local:AgentReport()

let $page := xdmp:tidy(xdmp:quote($xml), 
                      <options xmlns="xdmp:tidy">
                      <input-xml>true</input-xml>
                      </options>)[2]

let $tables := $page

let $sheet1 :=   <worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"> 
                <sheetData> {local:getRows($tables)} </sheetData> 
                </worksheet> 

let $sheet2 :=   <worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"> 
                <sheetData> {local:getRows($tables)} </sheetData> 
                </worksheet> 

let $package := local:generate-simple-xl-ooxml($content-types, $workbook, $rels, $workbookrels, $sheet1, $sheet2) 

let $filename := "ExcelTest.xlsx" 

let $disposition := concat("attachment; filename=""",$filename,"""") 

let $x := xdmp:add-response-header("Content-Disposition", $disposition) 

let $x := xdmp:set-response-content-type("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") 

let $insertReport := xdmp:document-insert(concat("/GroupNumberReport/Group-", $day, ".xlsx"), $package, (), "GroupReport")

let $saveReport := xdmp:save(concat("C:\EriePoc\DataStage-Demo\Report\Group-", $day, ".xlsx"), $package)

return fn:true()
```

Comment: Sure, I removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you had an additional Relationship element that is not needed, and causing issues.

Change your `$rels` variable to:

```
let $rels :=  
  <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"> 
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="workbook.xml"/>           
  </Relationships>
```

Unfortunately, MS Office doesn't often provide any helpful indications of where or what errors there are. Things either work, or they blow up with little information about what is wrong.

I find it helpful to test small changes, as well as working from a working instance file within the MS Office app, save, and then compare the individual files in the *.xlsx zip to discover the subtle differences between what works and what doesn't.